# Insert value into ObjectNode and return JsonNode in Jackson json library

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to insert a value into a json object in the following format and save it to the database.

```
  {
        "mainObject": {
            "childObject1": {
                "validator": {
                    "dataType": "TEXT",
                    "regEx": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$"
                },
                "input": "Enter data value here"
            },
            "childObject2": {
                "validator": {
                    "dataType": "TEXT",
                    "regEx": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$"
                },
                "input": "Enter data value here"
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to enter values in the tag where it says input. Something like this:

```
{
    "mainObject": {
        "childObject1": {
            "validator": {
                "dataType": "TEXT",
                "regEx": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$"
            },
            "input": "Input 1"
        },
        "childObject2": {
            "validator": {
                "dataType": "TEXT",
                "regEx": "^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$"
            },
            "input": "Input 2"
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following code snippet in java.  I am able to insert data into the right node.

```
String output = "{
    \"mainObject\": {
        \"childObject1\": {
            \"validator\": {
                \"dataType\": \"TEXT\",
                \"regEx\": \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$\"
            },
            \"input\": \"Enter data value here\"
        },
        \"childObject2\": {
            \"validator\": {
                \"dataType\": \"TEXT\",
                \"regEx\": \"^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*{3,10}$\"
            },
            \"input\": \"Enter data value here\"
        }
    }
}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(output);
ObjectNode newMetadata = (ObjectNode)  rootNode.path("mainObject").path("childObject1");
newMetadata.put("inputValue", "Input 1");
```

My problem is how to update and write this back to the mainObject node. At the moment the child nodes input tag is updated with the value, i want to update the mainobject with this and save to database.

Comment: `At the moment the child nodes input tag is updated with the value, i want to update the mainobject with this and save to database.`. What do you mean? You want to update the tree and then write it back to a string?

Comment: @Bogdan, apologies for the question. Maybe it was misleading. Actually what I wanted was something which i had already achieved in the code i had pasted. I was looking at the wrong variable when i was trying to solve the issue and hence thought the right node was not being updated and decided to post here.i dont know how to close this question or mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already pasted the code that had the answer. I was looking at the wrong node. I mentioned in my previous comment, I didn't really see an option to close the question. To make it clear, the answer was that as soon as I write to the child nodes, the parent node will have the property as well. That is working code which does not really need a fix, as I said I was looking at the wrong node.